# Issues transfering .apk files from PC to phone using the cable. Sony Xperia Neo

Tags: file-transfer, apk, sony-xperia-neo-v

I want to transfer some `.apk` files to my phone to install the applications on it.

I've tried many ways of **downloading** and **installing** applications on the smartphone but to no avail, so I think this method is the easiest one for now.

The problem is whenever I transfer them to a folder (browsing the phone memory like a USB) I cannot find them on the phone or there is no installation available.

Where should I paste those `.apk` files on my smartphone to be able to install them?

My phone is **sony xperia neo l**.

Is it the same for other smartphones?

Comment: How are you attempting to find them on the phone? Pretty much any decent file manager app (third-party ones, anyway) should offer to install the .apk for you if you attempt to "open" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plug in your phone and drag the APK file onto the SD card. Then go on the phone and download a file manager (ASTRO File Manager is my favorite) from the Play Store. Then in the file manager find your apk file (it should be in /sdcard or /mnt/sdcard). Tap on the APK file and an installer should show up.

Comment: Right, but how to download a file manager when there's no way to download and install an app from google play?

Comment: @Gigili Download it from here: http://www.appsapk.com/astro-file-manager/ on the phone (this is an old version though). You can install it by clicking on the apk file in the Downloads app. After you do that ASTRO is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Use a SD card and put the APK file on that. Put the card into the phone (if it supports it) and open the files folder on your phones File Browser (Could be something differently named). Install it as if it were another app.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the best soultion but you can also install application directly to your Android device from PC using [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). Run this command in command line to install `.apk`:

```
adb install /path/to/file.apk
```